# How to get array list values and put into ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

```
 I am trying to put the array list value on ListView.builder. I am doing calculation with loop.
```

This is my global variable files.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 double finalPitchDia = 0;
 List <String> firstListItem = [''];
 List <String> secondListItem = [''];
```

This is my calculation file

[image: first i type values in text fields and then i press answer button then lead gears button.]

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:angles/angles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/answerCode.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/const_sizes.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/repeateCode.dart';
import 'itemList.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/views/pages/global.dart';

class Milling extends StatefulWidget  {

  @override
  State<Milling> createState() => _MillingState();
}

class _MillingState extends State<Milling> {
  TextEditingController _diaFIeldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _teethFIeldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _degreeFIeldController = TextEditingController();

  String depth='';
  String modcutter='';
  String dpCutter='';
  String dpCutterNumber = '';
  String teethNumber = '';
  String mdCutterNumber = '';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void gearCalculation(){
       var diaField = _diaFIeldController.text;
       var teethField = _teethFIeldController.text;
      var  degreeField = _degreeFIeldController.text;

       double diaField2 = double.parse(diaField);
       double teethField2 = double.parse(teethField);
       double degreeField2 = double.parse(degreeField);

       double finalDia = diaField2 / 25.4;
       double cos1 = Angle.degrees(degreeField2).cos;
       double finalCutter = ((teethField2 + 2) / finalDia) / cos1;
      dpCutter = finalCutter.toStringAsFixed(3);
       double moduleCutter = 25.4 / finalCutter;
      modcutter = moduleCutter.toStringAsFixed(3);
       double finalCutterDepth = 0.08534 * moduleCutter;
      depth = finalCutterDepth.toStringAsFixed(3);
       double tan1 = Angle.degrees(degreeField2).tan;
       double pitchDia = (((-((2 / finalCutter)-finalDia) * pi) / tan1) / 10);
       finalPitchDia = pitchDia;

       if(teethField2 < 14){
         dpCutterNumber = '8';
         teethNumber = '12-13 T';
         mdCutterNumber = '1';
       }
       else if (
       teethField2 <16
       ){
         dpCutterNumber = '7';
         teethNumber = '14-16 T';
         mdCutterNumber = '2';
       }
       else if (
       teethField2 <20
       ){
         dpCutterNumber = '6';
         teethNumber = '17-20 T';
         mdCutterNumber = '3';
       }
       else if (
       teethField2 <24
       ){
         dpCutterNumber = '5';
         teethNumber = '21-25 T';
         mdCutterNumber = '4';
       }
       else if (
       teethField2 <35
       ){
         dpCutterNumber = '4';
         teethNumber = '26-34 T';
         mdCutterNumber = '5';
       }
       else if (
       teethField2 <56
       ){
         dpCutterNumber = '3';
         teethNumber = '35-55 T';
         mdCutterNumber = '6';
       }
       else{
         dpCutterNumber = '0';
         teethNumber = '0 T';
         mdCutterNumber = '0';
       }
    }
```

Here is my loop function. i am calling this function in LeadGears button.

Whenever this function call my log cat print perfecr values 2-100 which i also want

and i am storing those array list values in String type variable firstListItem,

and i am calling firstListItem variable in ListView.builder file.

```
    void leadCalculation(){
      for(double i =2; i<101; i++){
        double firstNumber = i;
         firstListItem = [firstNumber.toString()];
        double loopField = finalPitchDia * firstNumber;
        secondListItem =[loopField.toStringAsFixed(3)];
        print('$firstListItem : $secondListItem');
      }
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>ItemList()));
    }

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:
        Text(
          'Lead gears calculator',
            style: appBarText,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0,top: 5.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Note:\n    Please put Dia of HELICAL GEAR,teeth and degree.',
                  style: noteText,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child:
              Container(
                height: size.height / 5,
                width: size.width / 1.05,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0,3),
                    ),
                  ]
                ),
                child:
                    ListView(children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                      Center(
                        child:
                        Text('Required Fields',
                          style: puText,),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          repeateTextFieldCode(
                              controller: _diaFIeldController,
                              lableText: 'DIA'),
                          repeateTextFieldCode(
                              controller: _teethFIeldController,
                              lableText: 'TEETH'),
                          repeateTextFieldCode(
                              controller: _degreeFIeldController,
                              lableText: 'DEGREE')
                        ],
                      )
                    ],),
              ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child:
                Container(
                  height: size.height / 2.0,
                  width: size.width / 1.05,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0,3),
                        ),
                      ]
                  ),
                  child:
                  ListView(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                      Center(
                        child: Text('Answer Box',
                          style: puText,),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                      repeateAnswerCode(cutterText: 'Dp C: ', cutterField: '$dpCutter /',
                      numField: 'Num: $dpCutterNumber/ ',
                      teethField: teethNumber,),
                      repeateAnswerCode(cutterText: 'Md C: ',
                      cutterField: '$modcutter/',
                      numField: 'Num: $mdCutterNumber/ ',
                      teethField: teethNumber,),
                      Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child:
                        Container(
                          height : size.height / 10,
                          width: size.width / 1.1,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 5,
                                blurRadius: 7,
                                offset: Offset(0,3),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text('Cutter Depth: ',
                                style: puText,),
                              Text(
                                  depth
                                ,
                                style: fieldsText,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  InkWell(child:
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: size.height / 15,
                      width: size.width /2.2,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      child:  Center(
                        child: Text('Answer',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Alfa',
                              fontSize: 20.0
                          ),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {
                        gearCalculation();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  InkWell(child:
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: size.height / 15,
                      width: size.width /2.2,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      child:  Center(
                        child: Text('Lead Gears',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Alfa',
                              fontSize: 20.0
                          ),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {
                        leadCalculation();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my ListView.builder file

[image: i am testing only one variable firstListItem and this is showing me only last value of array list please help me how to do this.]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/layout/const_sizes.dart';
import 'package:milling_machine_calculator/views/pages/global.dart';
import 'milling.dart';

class ItemList extends StatefulWidget  {
  const ItemList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ItemList> createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  @override
  void initState() {

    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Lead gears list',
          style: appBarText,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body:
      ListView.builder(itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){
        return
          Container(
          height: size.height / 10,
          width: size.width/1.36,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 5,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0,3),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                  ...getList(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: 101,),
    );
  }
}
List <Widget> getList(){
  List <Widget> childs = firstListItem.map((e) =>
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children:     <Widget>[
          Text(e,style: fieldsText,),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
          Text('secondListItem',
            style: fieldsText,),
        ],
      ),
      ).toList();
  return childs;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what exactly is you problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the whole list to one element. You need to add elements to the list.

```
void leadCalculation(){
  for(double i =2; i<101; i++){
    double firstNumber = i;
     firstListItem.add(firstNumber.toString());
    double loopField = finalPitchDia * firstNumber;
    secondListItem.add(loopField.toStringAsFixed(3));
    print('$firstListItem : $secondListItem');
  }
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>ItemList()));
}
```

Edit: I just noticed you are also adding the Text "secondListItem" to the getData() function. So it will continue to display that.
Also in the leadCalculation function that print statement will display all elements of each list every time it prints so that will look strange.

Comment: ok, i try, and would tell you.

Comment: ignore the secondLIstItem just see the firstListItem

Comment: i tried but this is my stack.
I/flutter (12550): [, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 2432 pixels on the bottom.

Comment: it is showing is row the whole list bro

Comment: it is showing all the aray is one row but i dont want this , i want only one value in a row,
like: 2.0
second colunm3.0
3rd coulnm4.0
4th coulnm 5.0

Comment: 2.0 in one row 3.0 in second colunm

Comment: plese help me bro

Comment: You need to work on your getList() function. maybe change the .map function to forEach